# Por que dá erro de o arquivo estar fechado se em cada iteração ele deveria abrir novamente?

Tags: python, python-3.x, youtube-api

Estou tentando fazer um código para que na minha playlist do YouTube.

O programa compara se o link de tal vídeo da playlist está incluso num arquivo txt. Caso esteja, ele não baixa o vídeo, caso não esteja, baixa e escreve o link nesse arquivo txt para que, na próxima vez que ele rodar ele não baixe o vídeo novamente.

Porém está dando erro depois da primeira iteração de que o arquivo está fechado, sendo que eu o abro em cada nova iteração. O que fazer?

```
import urllib.request as con
import pytube
def baixar(y):
    print("Baixando")
    yt = pytube.YouTube(y)
    audios = yt.streams.filter(only_audio=True).all()
    aud = audios[0]
    aud.download(r"C:\Users\joaov\Dropbox\Músicas")
    print("Download terminado")
k = 0 
root = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vrQWhFysPKY&list=PLViTG4xZB5MiktfNXT0OaxANraqLRgSQr"
texto = con.urlopen(root).read().decode("utf-8")
tag = '&index='
while k <= len(texto):
    sta = texto.find(tag,k)
    fnl = sta + len(tag) + 2
    link = root + texto[sta:fnl]
    arq = open(r'C:\Users\joaov\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\videos.txt','r')
    for linha in arq:
        if linha != link and linha != "":
            arq.close()
            arq1 = open(r'C:\Users\joaov\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\videos.txt','a')
            arq1.write(link + "\n")
            baixar(link)
            arq1.close()
    k += fnl
print("Baixados!!!")
```

Comment: Mas dentro do laço que percorre as linhas você está fechando o próprio arquivo.

Answer (score 2):

Em primeiro lugar: abrir e fechar o arquivo em cada interação é uma forma incorreta de usar arquivos, de qualquer forma.

Em segundo lugar, o seu problema provavelmente está ocorrendo  por conta da linha que faz `arq.close()` dentro do `for` - esse `arq` foi aberto uma vez só -  o arquivo na variável `arq1` é que é aberto a cada interação.

Você vai conseguir "desbagunçar" bastante do seu código implementando duas boas práticas aí:
A primeira é separar os caminhos de diretórios e nomes de arquivos do seu código - 
perceba que a pasta exata e o nome do arquivo são preocupações que você tem que ter, mas que não tem a ver com a lógica do programa. Além disso, claro, limitam o seu programa a funcionar só com esses nomes e pastas - o código assim não tem como ser reutilizado, nem por você mesmo, se trocar de computador. (vocẽ já faz isso de separar a vairável com a url `root`)

Isso se resolve simplesmente colocando esses nomes em variáveis distintas  e fáceis de saber quais são logo no começo do arquivo. Aí você pode ou usar essas variáveis diretamente no seu código - ou, melhor ainda, criar uma função que receba o nome de arquivo como parâmetro - essa função pode então ser usada como parte de um programa melhorado, que tenha uma interface gráfica, por exemplo (e você não precisa mexer em uma linha do código que já funciona pra isso - só chamar a função com o nome de arquivo novo).

A segunda boa prática - é menos universal, mas nesse caso ajuda: é usar os "gerenciadores de contexto" do Python para abrir seus arquivos, em vez de 
guardar o resultado do `open` em uma variável e chamar o `close` explicitamente. Basta usar o `open` em conjunto com o comando `with` do Python - você vai notar que fica impossível dar o "nó" que você deu fechando o arquivo mais de uma vez - uma vez que o arquivo é fechado ao fim do bloco do `with` - ou o seu laço `for` é executado com `arq` aberto, ou com `arq` fechado.

Uma terceira coisa legal é que a partir do Python 3.6 a classe `pathlib.Path` do Python pode ser usada no lugar de strings para nomes de arquivos - ela tem algumas vantagens - como centralizar num só objeto toda a funcionalidade desejada para arquivos:

bom, eu dei uma reorgananizada geral - a maior mudança é que trabalho com as mudanças em memória, em vez de ler o arquivo de novo em cada interação - você tinha um outro erro de lógica aí pra verificar se o link já tinha sido baixado ou não - esta versão traz tudo pra memória, (dados de texto desse tipo usam uma quantidade negligível de memória) - e uso a clausula `finally` de um try except para garantir que os links novos sejam gravados no arquivo - mesmo que aconteça alguma interrupção no processo. (não testei esse programa - mas mesmo que tenha algum detalhe errado, ele pode dar uma ideia para uma organização mais legal do código)

```
from pathlib import Path

import urllib.request as con
import pytube

video_file_path = Path(r'C:\Users\joaov\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\videos.txt')

download_folder = Path(r"C:\Users\joaov\Dropbox\Músicas")

root = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vrQWhFysPKY&list=PLViTG4xZB5MiktfNXT0OaxANraqLRgSQr"


def baixar(video_id):
    print("Baixando")
    yt = pytube.YouTube(video_id)
    audios = yt.streams.filter(only_audio=True).all()
    aud = audios[0]
    # Bibliotecas externas as vezes não funcionam ainda
    # com objetos "Path" - mas tente passar sem a
    # conversão para "str" abaixo pra ver se funciona:
    aud.download(str(download_folder))
    print("Download terminado")


def baixa_todas():
    k = 0 

    texto = con.urlopen(root).read().decode("utf-8")
    tag = '&index='

    # A chamada abaixo abre o arquivo, le todo o seu
    # conteúdo, separa em linhas e guarda num objeto do tipo
    # "set" que é mais eficiente para busca com o operador "in":
    links_baixados = set(video_file_path.read_text().split("\n"))
    links_novos = []
    try:
        while k <= len(texto):
            sta = texto.find(tag,k)
            fnl = sta + len(tag) + 2
            link = root + texto[sta:fnl]

            if link not in links_baixados:
                baixar(link)
                print(f"Baixando novo link {link}")
                links_novos.append(link + "\n")
                links_baixados.append(link)

            k += fnl
    finally:
        with video_file_path.open("at") as arq:
            arq.write_lines(links_novos)


if __name__ == "__main__":        
    baixa_todas()
    print("Baixados!!!")
```

Comment: Uma boa prática, que às vezes erro, é misturar português com inglês. Seria melhor deixar as variações iniciais do caminho em português, ou não?

Comment: Em algum momento no passado, a recomendação de estilo do Python dizia "só deix nomes sem ser em inglês se estiver 120% certo de que ninguém fora do seu país vai interagir com o código" (e era "120%" mesmo) - acho que essa frase caiu - mas o ideal mesmo é não misturar - se tem nomes em inglês, deixar tudo em inglês e vice-versa.